# sql - A query to retrieve information from two tables depending on multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

A query to get a list of all crimes with reason and the name of both the criminal and the police, that's what I am trying to achieve.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT crimes.user_police_id, crimes.user_criminal_id, crimes.reason, users.name
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `crimes` on users.id = crimes.user_criminal_id
```

That returns only the name of the criminal...

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(24)
);
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("Divergent");
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("SomeGuy");

CREATE TABLE crimes (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_criminal_id INT(11),
  user_police_id INT(11),
  reason VARCHAR(256)
);
INSERT INTO crimes (user_criminal_id, user_police_id, reason) VALUES (2, 1, "Corruption");
```

This works, but it gets only the police name

```
SELECT crimes.user_police_id, crimes.user_criminal_id, crimes.reason, c.name, p.name
FROM crimes
JOIN users c on c.id = crimes.user_criminal_id
JOIN users p on p.id = crimes.user_police_id
```

Comment: Um, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Join a with `users` a second time to get the police name.

```
SELECT crimes.user_police_id, crimes.user_criminal_id, crimes.reason, u1.name AS criminal u2.name AS police
FROM `users` AS u1
INNER JOIN `crimes` on u1.id = crimes.user_criminal_id
INNER JOIN `users` AS u2 ON u2.id = crimes.user_police_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double join. I prefer to query crimes so you'll understand why :

```
SELECT crimes.user_police_id, crimes.user_criminal_id, crimes.reason, c.name, p.name
FROM crimes
JOIN users c on users.id = crimes.user_criminal_id
JOIN users p on users.id = crimes.user_police_id
```

Comment: No you're wrong. I get "SomeGuy" as the criminal name and "Divergent" as the police name. Check your data.

Comment: Check your users, the ID of the police is not the one you added on crimes. That's probably why you added a LEFT JOIN ?